# markdown having multiple lists

Tags: markdown

I had some html like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
</ul>
```

This HTML was generated using CKEditor, but I got fed up with WYSIWYGs and decided to use markdown instead.

I then converted it to markdown.

My markdown looks like:

```
- 1
- 2

- a
- b
```

However my output from my markdown is this:

```
 <ul>
        <li> 1 </li>
        <li> 2 </li>    
        <li> a </li>
        <li> b </li>
    </ul>
```

I need two separate lists as per the html prior to conversion. Can this be done?

Comment: You could put something "invisible" between the lists, e.g. `<br/>` or `&nbsp;`. It'll of course show up in the generated HTML, so it's not a particulary pretty solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First I'll clarify the undesired behaviour, then I'll show you how to get the desired behaviour.

### Undesired Behaviour - Concatenated Lists:

Markdown implementations often concatenate lists separated by whitespace.

For example, the following markdown has 5 lists

```
- a

- a
- b

- a
    - b


- a
    - b
- c


- a
    - b
        - c
```

and it renders as one big list:

- a
- a
- b
- a

  - b
- a

  - b
- c
- a

  - b

    - c

### Desired Behaviour - Separated lists:

**To get separate lists to render separately, separate your markdown lists with something that maps from markdown to invisible HTML**.  Each of these work fine:

- an HTML comment: `<!-- -->`
- a linebreak: `<br>`
- a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

Below are 4 markdown lists using each of them

```
- a

<!-- -->

- a
- b

<br>

- a
    - b

&nbsp;

- a
    - b
- c
```

which render as 4 separate lists:

- a

- a
- b

- a

  - b

- a

  - b
- c

Answer (score -3):

You need this:

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
</ul>



<ul>
    <li> a </li>
    <li> b </li>
</ul>
```

Look how first list was ended by you  `</ul` and how it is corrected by me  `</ul>`.

Comment: That is a typo, but it doesn't matter, my markdown is what I am working with now, that was how it looked in the past. I updated my question

Comment: Not sure if this answer is a joke, but I can't stop laughing...